# jquery-ui - Autocomplete for json data

Tags: json, jquery-ui

I have this type of json input.
[ { "id1" : "val1", "id2" : "val2" }, { "id1" : "val3", "id2" : "val4" }, ...]

How do I parse this inside autocomplete plugin available in jquery-ui? Basically I want the val1, val3, etc. corresponding to id1 to be the part of my autocomplete text. Any suggestions on how can I proceed with this?

Comment: Is this from a remote or local data source? Can you show your autocomplete code?

Comment: It is from a local data source which I prepared from my sql table. Actually i didn't want to fire "like" query everytime when user enters something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete widget expects an array of simple string values or objects with properties `label`, `value` or both.

You can take your data and transform it into the proper format using the `$.map` utility function. This assumes you are making your AJAX request successfully and data is coming back:

```
$.getJSON("/url", function(data) {
    var src = $.map(function (el) {
        return el.id1;
        // or:
        // return { label: el.id1, value el.id2 };
    });

    $("#id").autocomplete({ 
        source: src
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/df6wB/

Comment: Thanks!! It did work. I was also thinking that there should be some mapping possible for the array elements. thanks for your answer. The link was also useful :)

Answer (score 0):

To convert JSON string to JSON object use [`$.parseJSON( ... )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).
Here `var jsonstring` is text that contains JSON text and nothing else. `parseJSON()` will fail if string is not valid JSON.

```
var jsonobj = $.parseJSON( jsonstring );
```

Then use that to insert [new options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) to autocomplete.

Get values from `jsonobj` this way:

```
alert( jsonobj.id1 ); 
alert( jsonobj.id2 );
```

Comment: Here jsonstring is an array as defined in my earlier post. I'm trying that array but the jsonobj is being returned as null. Any pointers on this??

Comment: If it is already object then you dont need to `$.parseJSON()`, you should add more details to your question to get better answers. **Few lines of source code is worth more than thousand words.**

Comment: I'm using this 
`$(document).ready(function () {
var sA = [];
$.getJSON("URL to my json object array", function(data) {
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
sA.push(val.v);
});
$("#id").autocomplete( { source : sA, minLength: 2, cache : false });`